# .gitlab-ci-yml regex check varible

Tags: regex, gitlab

Here is a stage in my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
check:
    stage: check
    script:
    - echo "Checking if commit tag is valid"
    - [[ $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ ^(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(-(0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(\.(0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*)?(\+[0-9a-zA-Z-]+(\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*)?$ ]] && echo "Git commit tag valid" || echo "Git commit tag not valid" && exit 1
    only:
    - tags
```

When linting it I get the error:

```
Status: syntax is incorrect 

Error: (<unknown>): did not find expected alphabetic or numeric character while scanning an alias at line 16 column 107
```

Line 16 is the regex line.

Comment: Try replacing `\d` with `[[:digit:]]` or `[0-9]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Unfortunately it did not help :(